# Running a webserver for JSP without running as windows service

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, glassfish, webserver

Problem: I don't have administrative as to install services in my machine. so i am not able to use glass fish/tomcat . I want to know is there is any work around this ? why cannot it run just as process ? Stuck up on this all i need is a simple server on which i want to run a basic web page(jsp).

Comment: Just don't download the Windows service variant then? Just download the zip. It's after all plain Java code which is platform independent and just requires a JRE/JRK. Stop thinking that you *need* an EXE for Java programs. EXE is only for C/C++/C# programs (such as Windows services, as Windows is by itself also written in that language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is a pure java application that indeed have windows service wrapper but it is absolutely optional. You can download ZIP file that contains tomcat distribution, open zip file where you want and run it using one of batch files you can find it its bin directory.

For example take a look on `start.bat` and `catalina.bat`

Answer (score 2):

`Jetty` is your friend to do so. It doesn't require any installation. All it needs a jar file to be in your classpath. Check out this link:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-jetty-start.html